# Construction of mysql table

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys, unique

I have project for school competition in timekeeping and I am stuck to solve tables construction.
Look at this following examples.

This can happen ->

---

Competition | Contestants

Swiming | John Smith

Driving | John Smith

---

You can see that same name is there twice, but not in same competition.

This situation is wrong, so how can i prevent following situation ->

---

Competition | Contestants

Swiming | John Smith

Swiming | John Smith

---

I want to avoid duplication in the same competition.

Comment: Homework-based questions which ask us to code everything for you will not be reliable.

Comment: Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-queryand add some data

Comment: There is not question in this post. Also: This is not clear. What is wrong with the first situation? What does that have to do with the next situation? "avoid duplication in the same competition" is barely understandable. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. What does your textbook say about situations like this? Please don't ask us to rewrite it or do your homework. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't change the table structure of the table, you could add a unique constraint on the combination of the competition and contestant:

```
ALTER TABLE competitions
ADD CONSTRAINT competitions_unq UNIQUE (competition, contestant);
```

But this really isn't a great solution. A more idiomatic approach would be to have separate tables for competitions and contestants, and then have an m:n table to join them:

```
CREATE TABLE competitions (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    -- other columns
);

CREATE TABLE contestants (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(100),
    last_name VARCHAR(100),
    -- other columns
);

CREATE TABLE competition_contestants (
    competition_id INT NOT NULL,
    contestant_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (competition_id, contestant_id),
    FOREIGN KEY competition_id REFERENCES competition(id),
    FOREIGN KEY contestant_id REFERENCES contestant(id)
);
```

Comment: Thanks...i didn't know that i can have in UNIQUE INDEX (or in PRIMARY KEY) 2 and more columns...:D